# jQuery rollover menu without images

Tags: jquery, html, css, rollover

I'm stuck with a seemingly simple rollover task.

Black is the default state, blue the hover state.

[image]

As you can see, in the default state only the latter digits show, at hover, the 20 has to be added (no problem), the colour changed (no problem) and the whole thing has to be vertically in the middle (**the problem**).

Here's a jsFiddle of what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/markushausammann/3YPXk/

What markup and CSS would enable such a behaviour **without** using images?¨

Edit: The markup doesn't really matter, it's a normal horizontal ul li markup. But here is an example of how the markup may look like:

```
<div id="nav-years">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="2002"><p class="supertext">20</p><p>02</p></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="2003"><p class="supertext">20</p><p>03</p></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="2004"><p class="supertext">20</p><p>04</p></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="2005"><p class="supertext">20</p><p>05</p></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And some CSS, but this may have to be adapted for a respective solution.

```
/* years navigation */
#nav-years {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
}

#nav-years ul {
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav-years li {
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav-years a {
    display: block;
    width: 35px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide us your html markup so we can help you :)

Comment: A [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful.

Comment: Off the top of my head you could change the height and width to force the text break. Would probably need to be `inline-block` though. A fiddle would be excellent.

Comment: Can't give you a jsFiddle demo, if I could, I wouldn't need to ask this question.

Comment: @Jack Changing the height doesn't move half of the content up and half down, it moves everything down. And my first problem is already that I don't get the lower portion of the content into the visible area.

Comment: @markus: thirtydot, and the rest of us for that matter, would like a demo of what you *have* as a jsFiddle. Not the final result you'd like. That way, we have something to work from to diagnose/solve your problem.

Comment: I'll prepare a jsFiddle!

Comment: Please see the jsFiddle in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, but good:

http://jsfiddle.net/vUCgm/

You want to start playing with line height, and the :hover psuedo-class.

Comment: Slight change: http://jsfiddle.net/vUCgm/1/ now the position is closely connected with a padding-top value, only one thing to change

Comment: @puppybeard dang, you beat me to the punch :)

Answer (score 1):

Really, this can be accomplished through CSS alone **(including aligning it vertically, *per original problem*)**, saving you a JS call. [**See jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/josh_max/ttF9V/)

Here's the new CSS, though for a quick look *(new code marked with comments)*:

```
#nav-years { display:block; height:70px; position:relative; width:400px; }

#nav-years ul { display:block; height:70px; list-style:none; }

#nav-years li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 35px;
    line-height:25px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    overflow: visible; /* added */
    text-align: center;
    width: 35px;
}

#nav-years a {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 35px;
}

#nav-years a:hover { 
    color: #00FFFF;
    margin-top:-12px; /* added */
}

/* added */
#nav-years a .supertext { display:none; }
#nav-years a:hover .supertext { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. You'll want to mess with the height of the `ul` and `margin-top` of the `lis` a bit to get it how you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/3YPXk/3/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3YPXk/2/

Only line-height and height in JS.

Keep `$(this).height(70);` all the time and change line height:

a -> `line-height:70px;`

a:hover -> `line-height:35px;`